# Concat functions in haskell

Tags: string, function, haskell, reverse, concatenation

I'm new to Haskell so I have lots of questions so I'd like your help.

> Make a function "func" that receives a function " f " (String -> String) type and a String "s" that returns the reverse of "s" concat with " f " application in "s"

I managed to make the " f " function like this:

```
f:: String -> String
f x -> reverse(x) ++ x
```

> console: f "HASKELL" -> "LLEKSAHHASKELL"

But when it comes to the "func" function I don't know what to do or type in the console. This code below worked in GHC, but I don't know why, it doesn't accepts entries.

```
func:: (String -> String) -> String -> String
func f s = (reverse(s) ++ f "")

console: func "HASKELL" "ROCKS"

<interactive>:49:6: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘String -> String’
                  with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the first argument of ‘func’, namely ‘"HASKELL"’
      In the expression: func "HASKELL" "ROCKS"
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = func "HASKELL" "ROCKS"
```

If there's a better way to do it, please can you tell me ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why `f ""`? The text seems to ask for `f s` instead. Anyway, you can't call `func` with two strings, the first argument must be a _function_.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that something was off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is almost correct, except that you did not use `s` as parameter for the function application with `s`:

```
func:: (String -> String) -> String -> String
func f s = reverse s ++ f s
```

You furthermore use the function the wrong way, since the first parameter is not a string, but a function that maps a string on a string. We can for example use [**`id :: a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:id) to return `s`, or [**`reverse :: [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:reverse) to reverse the string:

```
Prelude> func id "haskell"
"lleksahhaskell"
Prelude> func reverse "haskell"
"lleksahlleksah"
```